# Хелп по си шарпу.

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Вот мне вдруг стало интересно, за что так ценят и любят язык C#? Хоть этот язык является неким посредником(в виду синтаксиса) между Java и С++, но он все равно обладает целым рядом своих "неповторимых" синтаксических единиц. C# поддерживает .NET, и это главное, чем он превосходит остальные языки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С# - это ОО язык для платформы .NET framework, на котором разрабатываются приложения под ВИНДОУС (и не только). Аналогом является VB.NET, на котором можно сделать тоже самое - разница только в синтаксисе, но лично для меня вб является убожеством по сравнению с шарпом. Думаю со мной согласятся все си-подобные девы, но в мире кодеров имеется не мало людей, которые до сих пор любят и используют бейсик. Следовательно вопрос, как я понимаю относиться не к языку, а к технологии .NET, как таковой, потому что все на данной технологии можно делать на шарпе (не считая дополнительных и редких плюшек в виде низкоуровневых кусков на с++ или мало ли чего еще). На данной платформе можно разрабатывать не только виндоус приложения (WinForms, WPF), но и полноценные веб-приложения (asp.net, asp.net mvc) или АПИ для чего либо в виде сервисов, или же WCF. Более того, используя Silverlight можно делать "плюшки" для веб-приложений по типу шлеша, но на c# опять же. Это далеко не полный список возможных направлений разработки на платформе .NET и в рамках данного вопроса не совсем корректно говорить, что ето все возможности c# - ето возможности технологии, а не языка! (редактор форм - ето вообще относится непосредственно к Visual studio, а не опять таки языку!!!). Единственно, что еще хочу добавить, так ето вечные споры про веб-технологии между .NET и пхп. Единственный и неоспоримый плюс у пхп лишь в стоимости, так как связка пхп + майскл + апатч отлично живет на линуксе (который бесплатный, как все знают), а в случае с .NET вам все необходимо покупать и живет адекватно это все на винде зачастую (хотя есть моно и тд и тп, но ето уже другая тема). Так вот - любая задача, решенная на пхп, может с легкостью быть реализована на асп-нет например, но далеко не все, что позволяет сделать .NET можно реализовать на пхп.

UP: жаль закончилась возможность добавлять комментарии... По поводу ответа: он является ПОВЕРХНОСТНЫМ на не очень конкретный вопрос и не может быть расценен, как официальное определение языка, технологии, пособие для использования в научных работах со ссылками на данный материал, кандидат на официальные определения в книгах или еще чего-то. Все кто считает, что в данном ответе есть конкретные ошибки - указывайте на них цитируя мои слова с конкретикой о том, что вы считаете в корень не верным или ошибочным. В противном случае холивар в комментах считаю просто флудом.

Я считаю, что на вопрос автора данной информации более чем достаточно и все тонкости, точности, внутренности технологии и прочая доп. информация просто не тема данного вопроса.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо =)

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень общий и немного странный - уточните его и я с радостью поделюсь своими знаниями в етой области :)

Comment: Ответ не является корректным в определениях. Согласно спецификации (например, Ecma-334) язык C# опирается на CLI (среда исполнения и библиотека), реализацией которой является .NET Framework, Mono, etc. Однако требованием являются лишь определённые части CLI (Annex D в спецификации). ОС также не имеет отношения к языку, как таковому.

Comment: @AlexeyM, уточните, что вы имеете ввиду под некорректными определениями и где вы увидели в ответе что ОС имеет отношение к языку? Конкретику, пожалуйста, что именно вы оспариваете, ссылаясь на спецификацию.

Comment: Я хотел указать на то, что CLI и WinForms не привязаны к Windows. Что касается определений: C# опирается не на .NET, а на определённые по спецификации части CLI; .NET Framework это не более чем реализация CLI (как и Mono).

Comment: Не привязаны, но я всего лишь хотел сказать, что разработка в большинстве случаев на данной технологии ведется именно под ету платформу! Каким образом факт вашего уточнения указывает на не корректность ответа?

Comment: Напутано. Аналогом является vb.net... А managed c++ не является? Проект mono упоминается, но утверждается, что приложения разрабатываются "под винду"... Каша.

Comment: Вы мне напоминаете студенческие годы и придирчевых преподов, к-е требуют зубрешки теории и им плевать на понимание. По существу: в ответе НЕ сказано, что аналогом является ТОЛЬКО вб.нет - не правда ли? Моно упоминается и сказано, что ето другая тема - не так ли? Это всего лишь поверхностный ответ не оч трезвого человека в праздничный день на не оч конкретный вопрос, поетому ваши аргументы я считаю пока что необоснованными.

Comment: Часто точность полезна; хорошим примером может быть [рецензия книги Fluent C# Джоном Скитом](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/12/05/book-review-fluent-c-rebecca-riordan-sams.aspx); замечания к книге (собранные на Google Docs) скорее всего будут учтены в следующем издании. В данном случае рецензент (который, к слову, весьма неплохо знаком с языком и средой) считает, что точность формулировок важна.

Answer (score 2):

На C# думать удобно (особенно тем, кто изучал алгоритмы на Паскале и Си). Много готовых классов, не нужно изобретать велосипеды, но ничто не мешает написать собственный. Огромное коммьюнити, очень много документации на русском. Проблемы с производительностью решаются оптимизацией или выносом критических участков кода в библиотеку на Си. Ну и конечно же ASP.NET (MVC). Из бесплатных IDE есть [Sharpdevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). Довольно [много](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/CatalogCSharp.htm) готовых опен сорс проектов. Для линукса есть проект Mono, обычно немного отстающий, но тем не менее уверенно держится и продвигается вперед. Для GUI есть GTK#.

Answer (score 1):

Мне он нравится своей наглядность при создании форм. Всё очень удобно и понятно. Нет мороки с переводом строки в число, как в c++. Именно благодаря .NET Framework я его и выбрал.

Comment: Ясно. А вот по поводу наглядности при создании форм, ведь, например,  система Delphi обладает не менее наглядным конструктором форм. Но, как я понимаю, весь кайф именно в .NET Framework

Comment: Конструктор форм АБСОЛЮТНО не связан с сишарпом! Честно говоря не очень понимаю вопрос автора про язык...

Comment: Я сейчас одновременно работаю в Delphi(в универе), а сам на C#. И конструктор Delphi не идёт ни в какое сравнение с C#. Да весь кайф в .NET Framework. А синтаксис как в Java(очень похож).

Comment: Это все клево - но в чем суть вопроса автора? :) Каждый язык по своему хорош и решает свои задачи... Конструктор форм связан непосредственно с ИДЕ, а не языком.

Comment: Просто интересно, чем так хорош данный язык. Можно ли его использовать для интернета и т.д

Answer (score 1):

Я уже довольно долго программирую на C#, хотя всё лето учил VB .NET так вот, мне C# нравится, его простотой, я осваивал основы VB месяца 2, а C# буквально за неделю разобрался, мне он нравится что с него можно сходить к соседям Java и C++, хотя все языки .NETFraemwork прекрасны, но сравнивать с тем-же С++, то откройте Visual C# и Visual C++ и посмотрите где предлагают выбрать какой проект создать(console, win forms и т.д), у С++ их намного больше, С++ быстрее, C# красивее(как по мне).

Answer (score 0):

Для меня важна скорость разработки.

Comment: Под .net? Тогда уж F#.